# Does Einstein Email recommendations support different websites?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question so sorry in advance.

We have a website that has 3 versions (1 for each locale). A product may be in the catalog for 1 locale but not for the other locale.

Does Einstein email recommendations support this?

We already make use of the existing locale fields to make sure the currency is correct but I believe this is something completely different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.

You can create a column in your catalog that splits the locales. Then you could create recommendation pages and include a rule that say include "LOCALE1" which basically excludes the other two.

This way you are able to sort them out. But sometimes it is a little bit better if you have own business units for that because your recommendation scenarios have a limit of 100 elements and when you use these excluding rules your set of recommendation items becomes kind of small. Then you are kind of limited to other restricting rules that could be beneficial in other circumstances.

Comment: So basically adding a separate recommendation for each locale? And having a rule for each of those?

Comment: You would create a recommendation page for each locale and each region. so for example: Homepage-USA, HOMEPAGE-CAN, HOMEPAGE-MEX and then you have three rules that is only active for 1 region which says: Include USA for Homepage-USA and so on

Comment: Can you also have multi locale values for online availability? Such that a specific SKU is available on one site but not on the other?

Comment: No you cannot. Atleast I think so, that is not something i know guaranteed. Ask salesforce support if OnlineAvailablity can be localized, like the other fields. My guess would be "no" because they internally use it as "out of stock"